# What's the easiest way to have customisable YouTube playback speed settings?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, playback, youtube-javascript-api

How could I customise YouTube's playback speed setting so that I have more options? For example I often want to watch at 1.75x

Ideally I want to create something that allows me to have a default speed setting for different channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youtube interface [only allows you to select between a few preset speeds](http://adrianroselli.com/2014/07/changing-youtube-playback-speed.html) and doesn't save it.

You can alter the speed programmatically by modifying the playback control's parameters by the means of your browser.

The HTML5 player that is on Youtube's site doesn't appear to conform to any of the [embedding APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) (though the servicing code might conform to the [JS API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) in some form), but you can just [control the `<video>` element directly](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html). With Flash... all you have is the programming interface that the `<object>` exports.

The simplest, one-off method is with JS console. There's also a [Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-speed-controller/nffaoalbilbmmfgbnbgppjihopabppdk) and a [Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/youtubevideospeedcontroller/) for that (and probably more than one). Finally, Firefox has the [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) addon that allows you to add a custom JS to the page that can do anything a JS can - including this.